# Input and output rate question

Tags: gre-exam

[image]

Input: It would would take 12 hrs to fill the pool.

Output: It would take 3g/4h to empty the pool in 48 hrs.

I'm not sure how to approach this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pool must be filled to $36$ gallons in $48$ hours, the water must be flowing in at a net rate of $3/4$ gallon per hour. The input supplies $3$ gallons, so the output must be $3 - 3/4 = 9/4$ gallons per hour.

Comment: ok so to fill the pool 36 gallons/48 hours the net rate must be 3 gallons/4 hours . . . Input: 3, Output: r, NET input: 3/4 so NET = Input - Output or 3/4 = 3 - r ... 3 - 3/4 = 9/4 ... i think i get it . thanks